# How to pass variables through the same page to javascript a page reload?

Tags: javascript, variables, reload

Say I want to have a text box in my html code that the user enters height and width of a map.
and I want my javascript code to processes the passed variables and generate a map based on the values.

Here is my problem. I don't want to use the clunky prompt() function, it's really annoying, and is very limited.
If I use the form tag, and put a submit button it is going to refresh the page, and I don't want that, but I'm not submitting anything, only passing variables to my script.

because everything is going to be done by javascript, and nothing is going to be send to a server or any sort of database, I want everything to be done on the same page without any reload or refresh and the results to be shown immediately after user clicks on a button.

How can I do this?

```
<script>
function validateInput() {
// check if the values are numbers if not generate an error and return a false value
}
function getMapSize () {
// get the user input data and return it as an array
}

function generateMap () {
var map = [];
map = getMapSize();
// generate the map and show the result on current page
}
if (variables are set and they are numbers) {
generateMap();
}
</script>
Height:<input id="mapSize" name="mapHeight" type="text"></input>
Width:<input id="mapSize" name="mapWidth" type="text"></input>
```

Comment: Four similar questions, I'm sure there are more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082357/pass-data-from-a-dynamically-generated-list-from-one-page-to-another or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264253/sharing-a-variable-between-multiple-html-pages or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724106/how-to-exchange-variables-between-two-html-pages or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328717/pass-arguments-from-one-html-page-to-the-other

Comment: What have you tried or researched? I'm not even sure what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying to write a simple script that generates a graphical 2d map using images and based on user inputs. the user can edit the map and when he or she is done save it on their own machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Niels said, you can use a `<button onclick="getMapSize()" >Generate map</button>`

Btw, be sure to keep the id's of the input elements unique.
You can get the userinput something like this:

```
<script>

function getMapSize() {
    var height = document.getElementById('mapHeight').value;
    var width = document.getElementById('mapWidth').value;

    if (validateInput(height) == true && validateInput(width) == true) {
        generateMap(height, width);
    }
}

function validateInput(input) {
    // Validate input...

    if (isValid) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function generateMap(height, width) {
    // Generate map with the given height and width
}

</script>
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the response. So what is the deal with this return false stuff? how does it effect my script? It simply just prevents a post back?

Comment: if you use for the button something like `<button onclick="myFunction()">`, instead of a `<form>...</form>`-block, nothing will be posted to the server. This way only the function 'myFunction' will be called, and in that case myFunction doesn't have to return false.

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways for this. You could either patch the `onsubmit` of your form, returning `false` at the end, or just omit the form entirely and act on a `<button>` element's `onclick`. They're all similar solutions, the best one depends on the entire implementation.

I whipped up [a small sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/C8waf/) to show how to do it with a button, code boils down to:

```
<label>Width: <input type="number" id="width" value="5"></label><br>
<label>Height: <input type="number" id="height" value="5"></label><br>
<button onclick="$('output').set('text', 'Surface size is '
              + ($('width').value * $('height').value));">Click me!</button>
<div id="output">Not clicked yet</div>
```

Of course you'd split the `onclick` code out to separate Javascript in real code. I whipped the sample up with Mootools, but it's easily adaptable to jQuery or non-library JS.

Comment: What if I had a single function that handled both data validation and then returned multiple values after some calculations? How can I extract the values the function returns, but not the boolean return value, without having to discard the return false statement which prevents the post back?

Comment: Say I had :

function getCoordinates() {
var x;
var y;
var bitMapAddress;
// get user data
// check if the data is valid
if (data is invalid) {
document.getElementById('someId').InnerHTML = "Error!";
return false; // <--- does this end the function and prevent the rest of the statements from running?
}
// assuming the below statements will run only if data is valid otherwise there should be an if statement
// some calculation
bitMapAddress = x + y * (x+1);
// process the data
return [x,y,bitMapAdress,false] // <--- is this the right way to do it? to return false in order to prevent post back?

Comment: So if needed this function to path three values to some other function but at the same time returning false in order to prevent post back. what should I do? or is this not the right approach and all these task should be handled by separate functions of their own?